# Why are my divs overlapping eachother?

Tags: html, css

These divs should be under eachother, but they end up overlapping. I have already tried deleting the float and debugging each attribute within the code.

I am not sure what am I doing wrong. The rest of the page has a similar structure but it only happens here.

Some help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. I am fairly new to Frontend.

```css
.features-list{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.feature-card{
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px #e0e0e0
}

.feature-container{
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
}

.eyecatcher{
    color: #95C123;
    height: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.video-explanation{
    background: #7d7d7d;
    padding: 45px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="features-list">
    <div class="feature-card">
    <div class="feature-container">
    <div class="eyecatcher">
        asdasdasd2
    </div>
        <div>
            asdasdasd
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="feature-container">
            <div class="eyecatcher">
                asdasdasd2
            </div>
            <div>
                asdasdasd
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature-container">
            <div class="eyecatcher">
                asdasdasd2
            </div>
            <div>
                asdasdasd
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature-container">
            <div class="eyecatcher">
                asdasdasd2
            </div>
            <div>
                asdasdasd
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature-container">
            <div class="eyecatcher">
                asdasdasd2
            </div>
            <div>
                asdasdasd
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="video-explanation">
    Video Explanation
</div>
```

Comment: Because you set `width: 33%`

Comment: either clear the float or add `overflow: hidden` to `.feature-card`.

Comment: you have set `33%` width and set `100%` width

Comment: Unclear what you are asking; I don’t see anything overlapping in your snippet. Or did you actually just mean “next to each other” instead of overlapping?

Comment: @CBroe `.features-list` and `.video-explanation` are overlapping.

Comment: do you facing this issue on small devices ?

Comment: @JishnuVS I have this problem on mobile, laptop and big screen.

Comment: Can you people tell me why is it being downvoted when the problem is pretty clear and I added the snippet and everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment above either you have to clear the float or add `overflow: hidden` to `.feature-card`

**With `clear: both`:**

```css
.features-list{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.feature-card{
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px #e0e0e0
}

.feature-container{
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
}

.eyecatcher{
    color: #95C123;
    height: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.video-explanation{
    background: #7d7d7d;
    padding: 45px 0;
}

.feature-card:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="features-list">
  <div class="feature-card">
    <div class="feature-container">
      <div class="eyecatcher">
        asdasdasd2
      </div>
      <div>
        asdasdasd
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-container">
      <div class="eyecatcher">
        asdasdasd2
      </div>
      <div>
        asdasdasd
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-container">
      <div class="eyecatcher">
        asdasdasd2
      </div>
      <div>
        asdasdasd
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-container">
      <div class="eyecatcher">
        asdasdasd2
      </div>
      <div>
        asdasdasd
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-container">
      <div class="eyecatcher">
        asdasdasd2
      </div>
      <div>
        asdasdasd
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="video-explanation">
    Video Explanation
</div>
```

**Or with `overflow: hidden`:**

```css
.features-list{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.feature-card{
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px #e0e0e0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.feature-container{
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
}

.eyecatcher{
    color: #95C123;
    height: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.video-explanation{
    background: #7d7d7d;
    padding: 45px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="features-list">
  <div class="feature-card">
    <div class="feature-container">
      <div class="eyecatcher">
        asdasdasd2
      </div>
      <div>
        asdasdasd
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-container">
      <div class="eyecatcher">
        asdasdasd2
      </div>
      <div>
        asdasdasd
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-container">
      <div class="eyecatcher">
        asdasdasd2
      </div>
      <div>
        asdasdasd
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-container">
      <div class="eyecatcher">
        asdasdasd2
      </div>
      <div>
        asdasdasd
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-container">
      <div class="eyecatcher">
        asdasdasd2
      </div>
      <div>
        asdasdasd
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="video-explanation">
    Video Explanation
</div>
```

Comment: i have this issue too, but no floats in my entire site